# Accidentally used ETH address to receive token from polkadot

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot

I accidentally used ETH address to receive token from polkadot.

For example:

https://polkaholic.io/account/49zaADFp2kjgEJhmUWp1aq4zVc6fGBnSNFEUa4b2WAvxF73X?group=overview&chainfilters=all

Eth address : 0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1

Public key in polkaholic: 0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1000000000000000000000000

I am wondering, is there any way I can access my tokens with my private key? or can I use polkadot.js to generate a private key (I have private seed) to access to 0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1000000000000000000000000 address?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot access the tokens sent to the ETH address using the private key of the Polkadot address. This is because the ETH and Polkadot blockchains are separate and have their own unique addresses and private keys.

To clarify, an Ethereum address is generated based on a 20-byte hash derived from your private seed, while a Polkadot compatible address is generated from a 32-byte hash derived from the private seed.

If you were to attempt to generate a Polkadot account using the private seed from your Ethereum address, the resulting Polkadot address would be completely different from the address "0x9ebb1958fb8aecac3cb5c2f10aa473955f9c7ef1000000000000000000000000" you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only recourse would be to go to governance and propose a `force_transfer` of those funds to another address. Other force transfers have generally not been approved but I think signing a message from that Ethereum account ID is a pretty strong case of rightful ownership. Ultimately it'd be up to governance, though.